# Java XSS Sanitization for nested HTML elements

Tags: java, jsoup, xss

I am using JSoup library in Java to sanitize input to prevent XSS attacks. It works well for simple inputs like alert('vulnerable').

Example:

```
String data = "<script>alert('vulnerable')</script>";
data = Jsoup.clean(data, , Whitelist.none());
data = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(data); //StringEscapeUtils from apache-commons lib
System.out.println(data);
```

Output: `""`

However, if I tweak the input to the following, JSoup cannot sanitize the input.

```
String data = "<<b>script>alert('vulnerable');<</b>/script>";
data = Jsoup.clean(data, , Whitelist.none());
data = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(data);
System.out.println(data);
```

Output: `<script>alert('vulnerable');</script>`

This output obviously still prone to XSS attacks. Is there a way to fully sanitize the input so that all HTML tags is removed from input?

Comment: I mean, you realize, that your second example differs from the first only be leaving out the `<SCRIPT>` tag in the `String` ... This doesn't actually have a `<SCRIPT>` element in it: `<<b>script>alert('vulnerable');<</b>/script>` ... This is malformed HTML.  What are you expecting?  Furthermore, I have never quite understood the purpose of JSoup's XSS attack cleaners.  If you wish to simply eliminate `<SCRIPT>` tags, then just remove them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but a temporary workaround would be parsing the raw text into a `Doc` and then clean the combined text of the `Doc` element and all its children:

```
String unsafe = "<<b>script>alert('vulnerable');<</b>/script>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(unsafe);
String safe = Jsoup.clean(doc.text(), Whitelist.none());
System.out.println(safe);
```

Wait for someone else to come up with the best solution.

Comment: Thank you @1218985. Tried your solution. So far this solution looks good as it fulfills what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are unescaping the safe HTML that jsoup has made. The output of the Cleaner is HTML. The `none` safelist passes no tags, only the textnodes, as HTML.

So the input:

```html
<<b>script>alert('vulnerable');<</b>/script>
```

Through the Cleaner returns:

```html
&lt;script&gt;alert('vulnerable');&lt;/script&gt;
```

which is perfectly safe for presenting as HTML. See [https://try.jsoup.org/~hfn2nvIglfl099_dVxLQEPxekqg](https://try.jsoup.org/%7Ehfn2nvIglfl099_dVxLQEPxekqg)

Just don't include the unescape line.